# Action class cannot fetch changed value from jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts2, struts

I have hidden field in my jsp

```
<s:hidden id = "selectedCombo" name="selectedCombo" value=""/>
<s:hidden id = "xyz" name="xyz" value="2"/>
```

I need to change it before submitting it to action, so I have written script code as below

```
var e = document.getElementById("somecombo");
var app = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 

var combo = document.getElementById("selectedCombo");
combo.value = app;
alert(combo.value);

var e = document.getElementById("rolesForm");
e.submit();
```

At this point, value of "selectedCombo" is changed and giving me updated value in alert.

Problem :

- But I am not getting that updated value of "selectedCombo" hidden field in my action class. I am using struts 2 so I am trying to fetch value by OGNL.
- I am successfully getting value of "xyz" in my action class as its value is static. But not working with "selectedCombo" !!

Is it OGNL cannot store changed value ?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the problem of OGNL.

You are not setting value to hidden field `selectedCombo` instead you are setting value to JavaScript local variable `combo`

```
var combo = document.getElementById("selectedCombo");
combo.value = app; 
 ↑
```

Now, `combo` variable has value assigned by `app`.

You need to change the code to,

```
document.getElementById("selectedCombo").value = app; //now this will set the value
```

Comment: perfect answer. Thats works !!....m feeling so silly though:) Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Sometime such small mistakes happen, we are human beings. Thanks! :)